# Calling RXJava2 Completable in a cascade

Tags: android, rx-java2

Usually to implement cascading tasks we use flatMap .

Like ObserableA.flatMap(A->ObserableB)

However I have a situation in which I would want to have two Completables that are interdependent.

Completable OperationA;
Completable OperationB;

I need OperationB to only execute after Operation A.  Since there are no flatmap operators in Completable , how should I go about the situation?

Comment: I think you can make use of toObservable() then you can flatmap it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `andThen` operator from the first Completable.

http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#andThen-io.reactivex.CompletableSource-